# Spark refusing explicit broadcast join

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my pyspark code (v2.4) I join two dataframes: one very large, the other tiny (just a few entries). The small DF, however, is obtained as a summary of another large DF. 
My broadcast join maxsize thresholds are generous enough for a broadcast join to take place, but it just doesn't. Even when I explicitly call for it:
`df_large.join(broadcast(df_small), ...)`
physical plan still indicates SortMergeJoin. I get BroadcastJoin only if I save the small DF to a file and re-read it prior to the join command.

What other means do I have to enforce broadcast join?
As a background info:

1. Broadcast join is needed because otherwise there is an enormous skew
2. replacing a join with UDF seems like a bad alternative because this involves an early collect (though maybe broadcast join does it as well?)

Thanks

Comment: Hi there, are you sure that the dataset is not broadacasted?

Comment: Yes, the physical execution plan says SortMergeJoin, and I also observe a very strong skew that indicates that that kind of joining is taking place.

Comment: If your broadcast fails that might indicate that your executors memory is full. Also is the data skew that affects the performance of the join and not the other way around! A join will be very slow or fail in the presence of data skew

Comment: Hi @Go can you post a sample of your data and the join participating on the process?

Comment: Hi Alexandros. Thanks for following up. Memory should not be an issue, since the resulting small DF is really small (few entries), and regular SortedMergeJoin does work as well (especially after we take care of the skew by other means such as multiplexing individual entries). Unfortunately, I cannot paste the samples here, as the data is sensitive, but I might be able to answer specific questions about it. Thanks.

Comment: OK good then :) if you fixed the skew data you solved the biggest issue I believe